# How to automatically validate coupon and adjust price?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add a coupon to my checkout page, using an AJAX request that validates the coupon and updates the price accordingly. However, on loading the checkout view I get the **error message**:

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

referring to the line `<%= form_for @actioncode, method: :post ...` in the form where the coupon is entered. I've tried to follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277917/ruby-on-rails-and-coupon-model). How should I adjust my code?

**The set up:** @actioncode refers to a model where the admin stores actioncodes. Coupon_code is not included in any model but refers to the value that a user enters in the form. Coupon_code should be checked against the Actioncode model (specifically the 'actioncode' column) if the value exists (validation) and if so update the price based on the value in the Actioncode model in the colum 'discount'.

The **checkout view** contains the following form:

```
<%= form_for @actioncode, method: :post, url: {action: "check_actioncode"}, remote: true do |f| %> 
  <%= f.text_field :coupon_code, :placeholder => "Enter your coupon" %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Coupon Code" %>
<% end %>
```

**Routes:**

```
post 'check_actioncode' => 'actioncodes#check_actioncode'
```

In the **actioncodes controller** I have:

```
def check_actioncode
  @actioncode = Actioncode.find(params[:coupon_code])
  respond_to do |format|
    if !@actioncode.nil?
      format.js   {}
    else
      flash.now[:success] = "Action code not found or expired"
    end
  end
end
```

The **organizations controller** renders the checkout view:

```
  def checkout
    @organization = Organization.new(organizationnew_params)
    if @organization.save
      @organization.members.each do |single_member|
        single_member.send_activation_email
      end
      @actioncode = Actioncode.new
      @amount = 100.00
      @currency = "EUR"
      @description = @organization.id
      @transaction_description = "My description"
      @transaction_type = "S"
      @hash = hash(@description, @amount, @currency, @transaction_type)
      render 'checkout'   # This renders the checkout view.
    else                            
      render 'new_premium'
    end
  end
```

**Update:** If I add `@actioncode = Actioncode.new` to the controller that loads the view, I get another error message `undefined method 'coupon_code'` referring to the 2nd line of the form. `coupon_code` is indeed a variable nowhere defined but it should simply be a temporary value that the user has entered and that is checked against the actioncode in the model for validation. How should I do this?

Comment: have you tried `<%= form_for @actioncode, url: {action: "check_actioncode"}, remote: true do |f| %>`

Comment: Thanks, tried it and then on loading got a different error message: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` referring to the same line.

Comment: Alright that's progress, update your question with the relevant error message so we can take a look and further help you

Comment: I updated the original post. Not sure what you mean with "paste in the html rendering of your form_for". The form is directly included in the view file (so not a partial).

Comment: Ok, what about `<%= form_for @actioncode, method: :post, url: {action: "check_actioncode"} ...`

Comment: Using `<%= form_for @actioncode, method: :post, url: {action: "check_actioncode"} , remote: true do |f| %>` I also got the error message `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`.

Comment: What attributes does `Actioncode` have? If you don't have an attribute `coupon_code`, you will get an error when using that in `form_for`. What are you trying to do here: `Actioncode.find(params[:coupon_code])`? `find` will try to find an `Actioncode` by `id` and I assume that's not what you want.

Comment: Actioncode has the following attributes in its migration file: actioncode, description, price, discount and code_exp_date.  
With `@actioncode = Actioncode.find(params[:coupon_code])` I try to do the following: I try to find the actioncode that corresponds to the coupon_code that the user has entered. If found (`if !@actioncode.nil?`) then the javascript file should be executed (yet to build this script but it should validate the coupon_code and update the price accordingly).

Comment: Do I understand you correctly yhat i should add `coupon_code` in a model?

Comment: No, the attribute in your model is apparently called `actioncode`, so you should change your form and controller to use `actioncode` instead of `coupon_code`. See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form to:

```
<%= form_for @actioncode, method: :post, url: {action: "check_actioncode", :controller => 'actioncodes'}, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :actioncode, :placeholder => "Enter your coupon" %>
```

Change your controller to:

```
def check_actioncode
  @actioncode = Actioncode.where(:actioncode => params[:actioncode][:actioncode]).first

  respond_to do |format|
    unless @actioncode.blank?
      format.js {}
    else
      flash.now[:success] = "Action code not found or expired"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I did as directed but get the error message: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`, which refers to `form_for @actioncode …` line.

Comment: There is a distinction beween actioncode and coupon_code. There is an actioncode model that only the admin writes data to. This model contains all the actioncodes users might use when paying for an account. Coupon_code refers to the value an user has entered at checkout. The idea is to then check if coupon_code is present in the actioncodes model. If so: apply the conditions corresponding to the right actioncode record. Like the actioncodes model, the user model also has a column called 'actioncode'. The idea is to after checkout to write the id of used actioncode to this last column.

Comment: With all the testing that I'm trying, I had accidently commented out one of the lines in the controller. Correcting this, and new I have the error message: `No route matches {:action=>"check_actioncode", :controller=>"organizations"}`. But as you can see in the original post, the route is defined.

Comment: No, it's not defined. The `check_actioncode` method is in the `actioncodes` controller, not the `organizations` controller.

Comment: I don't see any reason for having a `coupon_code` attribute.

Comment: Ah, now I wonder what would be best. Should I just move the method to the organizations controller? It makes most sense to have the `check_actioncode` method in the actioncodes controller. Also I had expected that for this method it would look in the actioncodes controller, since in routes it says **actioncodes**#check_actioncode.

Comment: No, don't move it to the organizations controller. Just add the controller to the url option in the form. See updated answer.