# Controller method / Javascript that validates coupon code and updates price

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a checkout page where a visitor can enter a coupon and thereby get a discount. Also I have an actioncode model with all the possible valid actioncodes, which are generated by the admin. One can submit a coupon and then upon pressing a button, it should validate the coupon and if valid automatically update the price. I've tried following the steps in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277917/ruby-on-rails-and-coupon-model), but am not completely sure how to do this.

Of course, this should be done in a secure way. My initial plan was through Javascript but the answers here convinced me this should be done in the controller (and possibly use Javascript to update the amount shown on the checkout view?).

How should I adjust the code below to include the coupon and what Javascript should I include? As it is right now, nothing happens when I press the coupon button.

---

**Routes**, which on submitting a new user executes `def checkout`:

```
post 'signup/register' => 'organizations#checkout', as: 'signup_checkout'
```

The **controller method that saves the new user and generates the view** for checkout (payments). It sets various variables for checkout:

```
  def checkout
    @organization = Organization.new(organizationnew_params)
    if @organization.save
      @organization.members.each do |single_member|
        single_member.send_activation_email
      end
      @actioncode = Actioncode.new
      @amount = 100.00
      @currency = "EUR"
      @description = @organization.id
      @transaction_description = "My description"
      @transaction_type = "S"
      @hash = hash(@description, @amount, @currency, @transaction_type)
      render 'checkout'   # This renders the checkout view.
    else                            
      render 'new_premium'
    end
  end
```

**The form** view with the first four lines producing the form for the actioncode/coupon:

```
<%= form_for @actioncode, method: :post, url: {action: "check_actioncode", :controller => 'actioncodes'}, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :actioncode, :placeholder => "Enter your coupon" %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Coupon Code" %>
<% end %>

<form action="https://secure.paylane.com/order/cart.html" method="post" >
  <%= "If you have a coupon, please enter that first. The amount due is #{@currency} #{number_with_precision(@amount, precision: 2)}. The button below will bring you to the secure environment of PayLane where you can select your payment method." %>
  <!-- form adapted from http://devzone.paylane.com/secure-form-guide/implementation/ -->
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value=@amount />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency" value=@currency />
  <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value=PAYLANE_ID />
  <input type="hidden" name="description" value=@description />
  <input type="hidden" name="transaction_description" value=@transaction_description />
  <input type="hidden" name="transaction_type" value=@transaction_type />
  <input type="hidden" name="back_url" value="https://mysite/signup/confirmation" />
  <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hash" value=@hash />
  <input type="hidden" name="customer_email" value=@member.email />
  <button type="submit">Pay with PayLane</button>
</form>
```

**Routes**, executing on submitting the coupon button:

```
post 'check_actioncode' => 'actioncodes#check_actioncode'
```

The **controller method executed upon pushing the button for the actioncode/coupon**:

```
def check_actioncode
  @actioncode = Actioncode.where(:actioncode => params[:actioncode][:actioncode]).first
  respond_to do |format|
    unless @actioncode.empty?
      unless @actioncode.price.empty?
        @amount = @actioncode.price     # It it safe this way, or should (part of) the method be private?
        format.js {}             # What should the js file look like to update the values in the checkout view?
        render 'checkout'        # To reload page with the updated price/amount?
      else
        unless @actioncode.discount.empty?
          @amount = @amount * (100 - @actioncode.discount)  # Not sure how to do this. The first @amount should be yhr new amount, while the second @amount should be the initial amount.
          format.js {}
          render 'checkout'
        else
          flash.now[:danger] = "Action code offers no discount"
        end
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Action code not found or expired"
    end
  end
end
```

*Removed the initial Javascript code, since answers suggest that is not a safe way to for example update amounts.*

Comment: Anything you bring to the UI is accessible to end user somehow.. So validate always in backend

Answer (score 2):

Few things to be noted,you would never bring action codes to UI.People will hack this for sure!

```
function validate(actioncode) {

    //Here make a call to your backend to validate. I RECOMMEND NOT TO DO IT IN UI.
    //Return somevalue
    //if you have the data in UI, you can use if(validActionCodes.indexOf(actioncode))
    if (isActionValid)
        window.alert("Action Code Accepted! Click the Buy Now button to finalize the payment");
    } else {
        window.alert("Sorry, The Action Code you entered is invalid. Please check and try again!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never validate critical user-input clientside (in other words here: with javascript), only. It would be a security leak and target for possible code injection attacks.
Why don't you just send the form inputs via `post` to your controller and validate it there with ruby? I think this would be more conform keeping MVC in mind (the view should not talk to the model).

Comment: But then the code would not be validated and the price would not automatically be updated. Or would it? 

I thought I would do both: controller and Javascript. Controller for security reasons and Javascript so that validation and price update immediately automatically take place on the checkout page. I think this is also suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277917/ruby-on-rails-and-coupon-model.

Or can this also be achieved through the controller, since the coupon code form also now includes a button?

Comment: as per my understanding in that question, they validate in Ruby and send the boolean to JavaScript to proceed.. Not the action codes itself..

Comment: Could you help me implement this? Not sure how I should change my code for this. I've updated `def check_actioncode` to (also) do the validation and amount update in the controller.

Comment: Just serve an own submit button for the code, that posts it to your controller. Than reload your page with the updated price. If you don't want to reload the complete page I recommend you to read something about AJAX, which gives you the ability to do requests without reloading and update only parts of your page :) AFAIK there are already a few helpers / modules coming with rails, making programming with AJAX comfortable.

Comment: But isn't that what I'm already doing in my code? I have a seperate form for the coupon and tried to follow the steps on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277917/ruby-on-rails-and-coupon-model, which indeed uses AJAX. Is my code nevertheless not correct yet?

Comment: Hum ... ok, sorry, I didn't read that :remote stuff :D of course you need JavaScript to update your price. I'm not sure how safe ruby handles user-input, especially according to SQL-injections. But I think it should be ok. In your check_actioncode.js.erb you provide the clientside-code to update your price (can't see which elements in your view should be updated, so I can't offer you code). I'm not sure what your @amount is for.

Comment: I guess render 'checkout' doesn't fit here. Wouldn't it render the whole view again?